# ExecutorService that cancels current task when new ones are submitted

Tags: java, executorservice

Consider a user interface that accepts configuration settings for a service that takes a long time to initialize (for example, the parameters for a JDBC connection).  We want our user interface to remain responsive while the service initialization occurs.  If the user makes additional changes, the initialization should be cancelled and restarted using the new parameters.

Because parameters are incorporated in the configuration as the user types each character, it's possible that a number of initialization requests could be created in a row.  Only the last one should be executed.

We have code that we've put together that achieves this result, but it seems like this behavior is a very good candidate for implementation as an ExecutorService.  Before we refactor everything into an ExecutorService, I figured I would ask if there are similar implementations already out in the world.

To be more specific:

The ExecutorService would have one worker thread.  As soon as a new task is submitted, the current task is cancelled (and the worker interrupted).  The new task is then captured for the next execution.  If another task is submitted, the current task is cancelled again, and the "next execution" task is set to this new task.  When the worker thread finally picks up the next task for execution, it will always be the last task submitted - all other tasks are either cancelled or discarded.

Does anyone have an implementation like that they'd be willing to share?  Or is there maybe a standard library that covers this type of behavior?  It's not hard to implement, but getting the thread safety nailed down can be tricky, so I'd rather use proven code if we can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I eventually came up with - I'm interested in any comments:

```
public class InterruptingExecutorService extends ThreadPoolExecutor{
    private volatile FutureTask<?> currentFuture;

    public InterruptingExecutorService(boolean daemon) {
        super(0, 1, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), 
                daemon ? new DaemonThreadFactory() : Executors.defaultThreadFactory());

    }

    public static class DaemonThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
        ThreadFactory delegate = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = delegate.newThread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }

    }

    private void cancelCurrentFuture(){
        // cancel all pending tasks
        Iterator<Runnable> it = getQueue().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            FutureTask<?> task = (FutureTask<?>)it.next();
            task.cancel(true);
            it.remove();
        }

        // cancel the current task
        FutureTask<?> currentFuture = this.currentFuture;
        if(currentFuture != null){
            currentFuture.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        cancelCurrentFuture();
        if (!(command instanceof FutureTask)){ // we have to be able to cancel a task, so we have to wrap any non Future
            command = newTaskFor(command, null);
        }
        super.execute(command);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        // it is safe to access currentFuture like this b/c we have limited the # of worker threads to only 1
        // it isn't possible for currentFuture to be set by any other thread than the one calling this method
        this.currentFuture = (FutureTask<?>)r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        // it is safe to access currentFuture like this b/c we have limited the # of worker threads to only 1
        // it isn't possible for currentFuture to be set by any other thread than the one calling this method
        this.currentFuture = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, made interruptWorkers in a better way. that items from getQueue() could cast to FutureTask is the key to the problem

Comment: Funny enough, I found that the execute() method gets in the way of that cast.  So I wound up with a different implementation that overrides execute, checks to see if a FutureTask is being passed in, and if not, wraps it.  The final code is actually cleaner, and works no matter how the ExecutorService is used - I'll post the update when I've got my code handy if I can remember.  End result, BTW, is very slick - all sorts of use-cases.

Comment: Calling `submit()` on classes that extends `AbstractExecutorService` immediately calls method `execute()` that is overrided here, so `getQueue()` will ALWAYS return empty queue. I think that you can remove code that try to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

you may need add a DiscardOldestPolicy to your executor

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.html

```
You will get
0 submitted
1 submitted
2 submitted
3 submitted
4 submitted
5 submitted
6 submitted
7 submitted
8 submitted
9 submitted
9 finished

public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
        NoSuchMethodException {

    final Method interruptWorkers = ThreadPoolExecutor.class
            .getDeclaredMethod("interruptWorkers");
    interruptWorkers.setAccessible(true);

    ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
            new RejectedExecutionHandler() {

                @Override
                public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r,
                        ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                    if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                        try {

                            interruptWorkers.invoke(executor);
                            executor.execute(r);

                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


    for(int i =0 ;i<10;i++)
        executor.submit(newTask(i));
}

private static Runnable newTask(final int id) {
    return new Runnable() {
        {

            System.out.println(id + " submitted");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(5000l);
                System.out.println(id + " finished");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: ah - very elegant...  Having to hit interruptWorkers method is a little disconcerting, but that sure does seem like the best approach here.

Comment: ok - interruptWorkers isn't part of the JDK that I'm running (Oracle, 1.6.0_34), so that's not going to work.  Other thoughts on an approach that would work using the public apis?

Comment: i am using openjdk 1.6.0_24 and get that from source

Comment: private void interruptWorkers() {
        final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
        mainLock.lock();
        try {
            for (Worker w : workers) {
                try {
                    w.thread.interrupt();
                } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
                }
            }
        } finally {
            mainLock.unlock();
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah - it's not in 1.6.0_34 (I think this underscores the danger of trying to use a private member function).  I have some further concerns that even if this did work, it effectively winds up blocking the input operation as the interruptWorkers/executor.execute(r) calls get called repeatedly until the worker actually releases.